# How to connect a Machine Learning classifier to a Web App?

Tags: python, node.js, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to build a sentiment classifier web app, but I don't understand who to connect the machine learning component with the web app. I've built the client-side web app that's running on a NodeJS server, and I've trained a sentiment classifier that saved as a Python script.

My goal is to have users submit text on the web app, send it to the Python script, classify, and send the result back via JSON.

How should I setup the Machine Learning-Web App pipeline?

One suggestion was to load the Python script in Flask, and use Flask as a REST API. It seems as though using Flask would be overkill since I only need to do one task.

Answer (score 2):

Flask is a relatively simple web framework. It will suit your need to get the user-submitted text into a python function, without too much boilerplate code or complexity. There are alternatives, most notably Tornado.

I do wonder why you would stack two REST interfaces on top of eachother. Do you need the node.js application for specific reasons? If not, you can simplify your architecture.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have a particular reason for why I'm using Node. I'm most familiar with it compared to other frameworks which is why I used it.

Comment: If the node app isn't doing anything (load balancing, DoS protection, security, other applications, ...), I would get rid of the node app and just expose the Flask interface.

Answer (score -1):

Your two main options are through a web framework, like `Flask`, or with a [CGI bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface), simply speaking it's like writing/reading directly to the terminal.

I wrote a tutorial, where I call the combine work of FullStack and Machine Learning : [Smart Stack](https://medium.com/@nebiljabari/meteorning-b0c27f42f93c#.s8vu20w9e)
using `Meteor - Angular2` and `Scikit-learn`.

The part which will interest you is the second: 2- Server Side and possibly the third: 3- Model Optimisation

I have some concern about the scalability of this process over `REST` style *(I have to dig deeper into that point)*, but for a prototype and/or a small app it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- It is recommended to spell out the answer here on SO instead of linking to an external site.